# extracting value from query parameter in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have the following XML. I understand its partial but the main chunk of it in the question.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<autnresponse xmlns:autn='http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/'>
    <action>GRL</action>
    <response>SUCCESS</response>
    <responsedata>
        <logentry>
            <autn:action>GETQUERYTAGVALUES</autn:action>
        

<autn:request>action=GETQUERYTAGVALUES&amp;outputencoding=UTF8&amp;securityinfo=MzU2fOF%2B5eSQuqdOYyq0j8%2F1oA3pmjQzOeS88Ddrt%2F0kO7ONSKKhD%2BTEScNxjEatqmV%2FJjFWdAD8JMpbv0WRQ%2F2MhQuHZpBpAdWbrTCSkA2xrWRsJp3hpqLk6r6xQM9s0rtaiWnq7hIxdhvJbQhDvKu2zIsmNXxPWbuU%2FOFYejT8Ku62opQP6cY415GJGmVUAkYSXRGjfOWRbvBygPEu48Wsc4V9UHfV2gUnTgJWOqlfnL738qGuCZdVfly5orlmH2qHNhZzet4ZuDmXk%2BI8dbxMdNeI9SgL1VwpeewVKyARciJn%2BiImL2HObDcx%2Bxn9ik%2FfeJ6YkdPQJeULr4QMJlVaDpxiBlLVuA%2FLYPvj0ErQaf%2FtFIJB5W32p2b5eLNVCGQZjSztssDAqtqEPhwAy0KmxGpr%2Bxl7SYfCKNhZwLGShc6EjqqsmYslNWhmuI2aZJxQV3J5tH2Z1GI2epbEKmgz0e4%2BLhQS&amp;databasematch=Exchange%2BFileshare%2BSharePoint%2BMicrosoftTeams&amp;combine=Simple&amp;predict=true&amp;sort=DocumentCount&amp;anylanguage=true&amp;start=1&amp;documentcount=true&amp;valuerestriction=&amp;fieldname=TS%5FINDUSTRY%2CTS%5FCLASSIFICATION%2CDOCUMENT%5FMETADATA%5FFROM%5FSTRING%2CDOCUMENT%5FMETADATA%5FCREATOR%5FSTRING%2CTS%5FPOLICYTYPE%2CACCOUNT%5FNUMBEROFEMPLOYEES%2CIMPORTMAGICEXTENSION%2CACCOUNT%5FBILLINGCITY%2CDOCUMENT%5FMETADATA%5FHASATTACHMENTS%5FBOOLEAN%2CTS%5FNUMBER%2CDOCUMENT%5FMETADATA%5FAUTHOR%5FSTRING%2CTS%5FCONTAINER%2CDOCUMENT%5FKEYVIEW%5FCONTENTTYPE%5FSTRING%2CDOCUMENT%5FMETADATA%5FPRIORITY%5FSTRING%2CDOCUMENT%5FMETADATA%5FTO%5FSTRING&amp;maxvalues=5&amp;valuedetails=true&amp;ranges=&amp;text=%28virtual%20assistant%29&amp;actionid=c0043eda74acecc482431d323defe9a1ccff35be&amp;fieldtext=
        </autn:request>
        <autn:client>::1</autn:client>
        <autn:time>01 Jul 20 12:41:23</autn:time>
        <autn:duration>19.00 ms</autn:duration>
        <autn:status>success</autn:status>
        <autn:thread>2</autn:thread>
    </logentry>
```

I am trying to transform it so that I can get the value of securityinfo in the autn:request element and render it as a cell in the table. Here is my XSLT I have made progress on.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Audit information</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="autnresponse/responsedata/logentry">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="autn:time"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="autn:client"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="autn:action"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Breaking up strings is easier in XSLT 2 or 3 with regular expression support or if your particular XSLT 1 processor supports an extension. Which processor do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(concat(autn:request, '&amp;'), 'securityinfo='), '&amp;')"/>
```

---

This is assuming you are limited to XSLT 1.0. Otherwise you could use regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using a recent Saxon version, it's

```
saxon:analyze-uri('http://dummy/?'||autn:request)?queryParams?securityinfo
```